# alert box is not poppomg out if linked to anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

WHY IS THIS NOT POPPING OUT AN ALERT BOX ON CLICKING THE LINK BEFORE GOING TO THE LINK????

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home.js';



function Admin() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>ADMIN WORK WILL BE HERE</h2>
      <a href="http://localhost:3000/" onclick="alert('You are going to be logged out!!');">LOGOUT</a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Admin;
```

Comment: Why not create a button with onclick and then trigger a function that runs alert and redirects? PS share a sandbox where we can edit your code and help you with it.

Comment: the problem is that you are inserting the alert functionality in double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>ADMIN WORK WILL BE HERE</h2>
      <a href="http://localhost:3000/" onClick={() => alert('You are going to be logged out!!')}>LOGOUT</a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: actually its working but i wanted the page to divert but at the same time the mesage should be shown "that u r logged out"

Comment: It will show the popup first then after accepting the alert, the page will navigate to the URL specified in the href!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arrow function to achieve this

```
onclick={() => alert("You are going to be logged out!!")}
```

Comment: actually its working but i wanted the page to divert but at the same time the mesage should be shown "that u r logged out"

Comment: what do you mean by divert? do you mean routing? search for react-router.

Comment: I mean while i click on the link the page should divert but at the same time it should show a message like alert "that u are logged out"